# How does unity refer a to a normal when there are so many?

Tags: collision-detection, normals, computational-geometry

When an object collides with another object, does unity calculate the normal, or return it from the list of normals?

Comment: Well it certainly does not store a list of all the infinite different normals associated with the infinite points on a sphere or capsule collider, nor even all the ones with distinct floating point representations. There's just too many to store, and they're trivial to calculate when needed.  I suspect though, what you really need to know is not "how specifically does Unity's PhysX/Box2D work" but "how can I implement something in MY game". Try **editing your question** to clarify what you're trying to do and what help you need doing it.

Comment: Are you asking "how does Unity itself determine which normals to report" or are you asking "how does Unity report collision normals"?

Answer (score 1):

How Unity calculates the collision normals depends on the types of colliders involved.

It's worth noting that unity will offload all of this to a physics engine (primarily [nVidia PhysX](https://developer.nvidia.com/physx-sdk)), so in a lot of cases it's not *actually* Unity doing the calculations.

That said, at a high level, there are 2 classes of collider/geometry...

##### Primitives

These are simple shapes (spheres, planes, capsules, boxes, etc)

Each combination of colliders will require a slightly different solution.

Eg If it's calculating the collision of 2 spheres, it's pretty trivial... PhysX knows the radius and center of each sphere. If the magnitude of the vector between them is equal to the sum of their radii, they're touching), and the normal of the collision can be calculated by looking at the sphere's velocities and doing a dot product.

A sphere and a plane involves calculating the distance from the center of the sphere to the nearest point on the plane and comparing to the sphere's radius, with the normal being perpendicular to the surface.

Each unique combination has a different mathematical solution.

As a rule, primitive-primitive collisions are relatively cheap (computationally).

(That's one reason Unity uses a capsule collider by default for the player controller).

##### Meshes + Height fields

For meshes, there are sub-categories...

###### Convex hulls

These are shapes with no overhangs/dips/hollows. You can draw a line between every pair of points on their surface and it will never leave the shape.

These are more complex to handle than primitives as it needs to compare collisions for many (but not all) faces.

(Obviously a mesh-mesh collision is worse than a mesh-primitive collision as there's multiple faces on each mesh to cross-compare)

Even so, there are optimisations to reduce the number of faces that need to be compared (beyond my ability to describe).

###### Concave meshes

Meshes with overhangs, holes, etc...

These are a real problem.

Unity *used* to handle dynamic concave collision meshes but dropped support when PhysX stopped supporting them (The recommendation is to use a number of convex hulls to build up a concave overall shape).

I *believe* that for concave hulls, all faces need to be checked every time, as there are no good universal optimisations that handle all the geometry edge-cases.

##### Further Reading

[This page](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Geometry.html) gives far more detail about how PhysX defines different types of colliders, and [this page](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/AdvancedCollisionDetection.html) explains how collisions are handled

[This one](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/RigidBodyOverview.html) explains the Rigid Body object hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Unity dev, but let's work it out. Unity has some excellent documentation. More often than not, the things that you might need to follow up on are linked from the places you've first found them. So you don't need to repeatedly use their search bar , Google follow stuff, etc - once you're on the trail, it's usually just a matter of clicking through to the next thing.

A quick search for "Unity collision" (I actually had a typo & looked for "nity" instead of "Unity") brings up the Unity docs Collision & we'll start with [Introduction to collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html):

> ...
> On the first physics update where the collision is detected, the `OnCollisionEnter` function is called.

So now let's take a look at the docs for [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). The description tells us its parameters are "The Collision data associated with this collision event." And further down, there's a couple of code samples including the following:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
    if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2)
        audioSource.Play();
}
```

Notice that the `foreach` loop is iterating over the contents of `collision.contacts`; And as it does so, the code is drawing some white rays that start at the point of contact and extending along the normal of the contact. So this is technically enough to infer an answer to your question, but as long as we're looking stuff up in the documentation, we can go a couple steps further to get a definitive answer.

We can go to the documentation for [Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) and from there look up the documentation for its [contacts property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html) which states:

> Every contact contains a contact point, normal and the two colliders that collided (see `ContactPoint`). From inside `OnCollisionStay` or `OnCollisionEnter` you can always be sure that contacts has at least one element.

We've learned that a `Collision` contains a collection of `Contacts`, that each `Contact` has normal and that within the `OnCollisionStay` or `OnCollisionEnter` methods, you are guaranteed at least one contacts (and therefore at least one normal), but there may be more.

So you're not exactly getting a collection of normals directly, you're getting a collision, which has a collection of contacts and the contacts have normals for their respective points of impact.

Comment: This seems to answer "How can *my code* look up the collision normal reported from Unity", but it sounds to me like the question was asking "how does *Unity itself* determine which normals to report" — am I misreading what was asked?

Comment: That's a valid observation. I read it as "how does Unity report collision normals", but your read of the question is also reasonable. I'll leave this up for now, comment for clarification & edit / remove based on the outcome.